# CASE WHEN na cláusula where e com THEN com mais de 1 valor de retorno

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Olá. Tenho uma aplicação para montagem de consultas, na qual passo os parâmetros na cláusula "Where". Só que deparei com uma situação em que preciso utilizar o CASE e na cláusula THEN um range de valores (para retornar em um IN). A ideia é mais ou menos assim:

```
select [...]
from table
where campo in 
            case 
                 when <condicao1> then 'Valor1'
                 when <condicao2> then 'Valor1', 'Valor2'
                 else 'Valor3' end
```

O problema é justamente na *condicao2*, quando forneço mais de um valor, que a sintaxe do case não aceita **'Valor1', 'Valor2'**. Alguém tem uma ideia se há um jeito de fazê-lo?

Comment: Casos em que o perguntador "some".

Answer (score -1):

Eu reformataria essa query para:

```
select [...]
from table
where
    (campo = 'Valor1' and <condicao1>)
    or (campo in ('Valor1', 'Valor2') and <condicao2>)
    or campo = 'Valor3'
```

Answer (score -1):

Vale lembrar dos operadores lógicos, se usar and (ele terá que validar tudo que estiver dentro), se for entre alguns dos valor utilize OR. Algo do tipo entre ficaria assim:

`where
(
  case when condicao1 then 'Valor1'
  or   when condicao2 between x and x then 'Valor2' 
)`

use o between para seu range.